# how to set header search path for external framework..?

Tags: iphone

I have added external framework in my application. Now i want to set header search path for that. can anybody help me for this...what it actually require to add?. I got No such File or Directory Error.
       I m using xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `${SRCROOT}` variable and then append the path to the required framework. Basically a path to a framework could look like this `${SRCROOT}/libs/kazmath/include` (for example a kazmath library header search path), so to make it generic, this should work `${SRCROOT}/path/to/the/library/headers` :)